# What is the replacement of replaceAll(Response) in Response entity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

Response has replaceAll which takes headers(type: MultivaluedMap).

What will be the equivalent code if I want to use ResponseEntity?

Response
.ResponseBuilder
.entity(entityValue)
.replaceAll(headers)
.type(APPLICATION_JSON)
.build();

Comment: What Response type are you talking about? Please mention the packages and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor with:

```
new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

headers is a *"MultiValueMap headers"*.